# Eog random slideshow from the terminal

Tags: command-line, slideshow, eog

What is the best way to have Eye of Gnome Graphics viewer (EOG) open a folder full of images in a randomized slide-show from the terminal?

Comment: Is this for personal use or for a program you are making? If the former, then you can just call `eog /path/to/folder` and press Ctrl+M so as to have a random image displayed...

Comment: I was hoping to build a shell script.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install eog-plugins -y
```

then start eye of gnome, (terminal or not, doesn't matter for now), click 
`edit / preferences / plugins`
Scroll down and check the "slideshow shuffle" box. Close the program.

Then, via terminal you can:

```
eog /path/to/pictures -s
```

Where the " -s" switch triggers the slideshow and eog remembers the shuffle plugin.